# ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled="False" or ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled="True" has no effect

Tags: xaml, windows-8.1, winrt-xaml

I am learning xaml and I am at Gridview. I have noticed that when I type in:

```
<GridView x:Name="Grid1" Grid.Row="1" SelectionMode="None"  Padding="120,0,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" d:LayoutRounding="Auto"
              ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled="False">
```

or

```
<GridView x:Name="Grid1" Grid.Row="1" SelectionMode="None"  Padding="120,0,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" d:LayoutRounding="Auto"
              ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled="True">
```

There is no difference when I run the app. I would like to know if "ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled" really does anything, or am I doing something wrong. Also same for "ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled"

I have been to MSDN, the explanation there doesn't help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To enable **horizontal scroll**, you need to do this

```
<GridView x:Name="Grid1" Grid.Row="1" SelectionMode="None"  Padding="120,0,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" d:LayoutRounding="Auto">
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled">

<!-- Inside XAML code here -->

</ScrollViewer>
</GridView>
```

To enable **vertical scroll**, you need to do this

```
<GridView x:Name="Grid1" Grid.Row="1" SelectionMode="None"  Padding="120,0,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" d:LayoutRounding="Auto">
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollMode="Enabled">

<!-- Inside XAML code here -->

</ScrollViewer>
</GridView>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, thanks but I know how to do that.  My question is what is the use or why would someone use "ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled" because, I don't see any effects when it is set as true or false.

Comment: You can use the `HorizontalScrollMode` and `VerticalScrollMode` properties to restrict panning to the horizontal or vertical axis or enable panning in any direction. You can use the `IsHorizontalRailEnabled` and `IsVerticalRailEnabled` properties to lock the motion to the horizontal or vertical axis after panning has started. You can use the `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` and `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` to show, hide, or disable scroll bars. 

To be more clear, take a look at this sample: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-ScrollViewer-pan-and-949d29e9#content