# UWP IsVerticalRailEnabled not working

Tags: xaml, uwp, scrollviewer

I have a `Scrollviewer` wrapping a `ListView` of movie posters, and it is scrollable verticaly and horizontaly and also zoomable.

When I set `IsHorizontalRailEnabled="False"` to the `Scrollviewer` the horizontal rails are effectively disabled, but whatever the value  I assign to `IsVerticalRailEnabled`, the rails are never disabled.

```
<ScrollViewer ZoomMode="Enabled"
              MinZoomFactor="0.1"
              MaxZoomFactor="1"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              IsVerticalRailEnabled="False"
              IsHorizontalRailEnabled="False">
    <ListView   Grid.Row="0"
                            Name="MovieListView"
                            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding movie_posters_list}">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsWrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="15" Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I cant find any helpful documentation about this weird behaviour, any idea how to correct it ?

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31358080/scrollviewer-ishorizontalrailenabled-false-or-scrollviewer-ishorizontalrailena

Comment: Whereas the post seems to show a similar problem, the answers given are loosely related :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT : As Justin XL mentionned in the comments, this way is breaking the UI virtualization of the ListView, and therefore should be avoided. See his comment for more info**

I found the answer myself. I do not fully understand why I had to do that for it to work but OK. If you have an explanation on why I had to duplicate the property usage I would appreciate it :)

All I had to do is add `ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled="False"` to my `ListView` element.

Note that I have to keep `IsVerticalRailEnabled="False"` in my `ScrollViewer` too for it to work.

Here is the updated xaml :

```
<ScrollViewer ZoomMode="Enabled"
              MinZoomFactor="0.1"
              MaxZoomFactor="1"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              IsVerticalRailEnabled="False"
              IsHorizontalRailEnabled="False">
    <ListView   Name="MovieListView"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding movie_posters_list}"
                ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled="False">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsWrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="15" Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: The `ListView` control has already got a `ScrollViewer` built within its `ControlTemplate`, you shoud be manipulating its inner `ControlTemplate` than wrapping it with another one. Note you should be using a `GridView` instead, which also has got a `ScrollViewer` built-in. Your current implementation breaks the control's default UI virtualization behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @JustinXL I applied them, works like a charm !

Comment: glad it helped! :)